# Outputting Non-Unicode from Mongoexport on Windows

Tags: mongodb, unicode, mongoexport

I am trying to export from a remote MongoDB to my Windows 8 system, and all of the special characters are unicode escaped, like the & here:

> http://blakecounty.gov/detail.aspx?sid=1444**\u0026**printkey=8675309

Can I just get those special characters unencoded? Is that something I need to set up system wide?

Comment: I don't know that there's an easy solution/workaround for this. What's the impact of having it encoded like that? How are you using the export / what are you trying to do? Is this a one-time thing?

Comment: You're right. This is good data that anyone can use. Thank you.